# SHAREPOINT: Custom Field type property storage defined for custom field

Tags: sharepoint, field

ok here is a great question. I have a set of generic custom fields that are highly configurable from an end user perspective and the configuration is getting overbearing as there are nearly 100 plus items each custom field allows you to perform in the areas of Server/Client Validation, Server/Client Events/Actions, Server/Client Bindings parent/child, display properties for form/control, etc, etc.

Right now I'm storing most of these values as "Text" in my field xml for my propertyschema. I'm very familiar with the multi column value, but this is not a complex custom type in sense it's an array. I also considered creating serilzable objects and stuffing them into the text field and then pulling out and de-serilizing them when editing through the field editor or acting on the rules through the custom spfield.

So I'm trying to take the following for example

```
<PropertySchema>
<Fields>
<Field Name="EntityColumnName" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="EntityColumnName" MaxLength="500" DisplaySize="200" Type="Text">
<default></default>
</Field>
<Field Name="EntityColumnParentPK" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="EntityColumnParentPK" MaxLength="500" DisplaySize="200" Type="Text">
<default></default>
</Field>
<Field Name="EntityColumnValueName" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="EntityColumnValueName" MaxLength="500" DisplaySize="200" Type="Text">
<default></default>
</Field>
<Field Name="EntityListName" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="EntityListName" MaxLength="500" DisplaySize="200" Type="Text">
<default></default>
</Field>
<Field Name="EntitySiteUrl" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="EntitySiteUrl" MaxLength="500" DisplaySize="200" Type="Text">
<default></default>
</Field>
</Fields>
<PropertySchema>
```

And turn it into this...

```
<PropertySchema>
<Fields>
<Field Name="ServerValidationRules" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="ServerValidationRules" Type="ServerValidationRulesType">
<default></default>
</Field>
</Fields>
<PropertySchema>
```

Ideas?????

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the problem but from what I understand, could you create a generic [field type property editor control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802857.aspx) and reference a editor user control in the xml rather than declare each individual piece of the editor interface declaratively?